# How send a JSON Object to View from another View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I trying to send a JSON Object with AJAX from a Index View to Controller, than from Controller to the method New and than Redirect to the New View.

My JS code From Index View:

```
function  startStrip(id, name, s_date, num, id_type, price){
            if (num == "") {
                num = 0;
            } else {
                num = parseInt(num);
            }
            var item = {
                itemId: parseInt(id),
                name: name,
                startDate: s_date.split(' ')[0],
                startTime: s_date.split(' ')[1],
                itemNum: num,
                IDItemType: parseInt(id_type),
                price:price
            }
            console.log(item);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("New","Congress")',
                data: JSON.stringify(item), 
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("sucess= "+response);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("error= "+err);
                }
            });

        }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(NewCongressViewModel viewModel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(viewModel);

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

The problem is that the controller returns an HTML code and does not take me to the indicated View

Comment: What is the indicated `View`? Can you please elaborate more on your problem. Thanks

Comment: @julio what you are getting in viewModel?

Comment: @NijinKoderi getting the Json object that I send from Java Script

Comment: @RahulSharma the post is updated.

Comment: @Julio If you want to preserve your `Model` you can do: `return View("New",viewModel)`. If you do a redirect then your `Model` values are lost and you would have to persist your values using `TempData`. Basically my point is that you cannot redirect with your entire `Model` because redirects are simply an empty response with a 301, 302, or 307 status code, and a Location response header. That Location header contains the the URL you'd like to redirect the client to

Comment: @RahulSharma you know another way how i can send the Json to the new View?

Comment: @Julio What do you mean by Json? Do you mean how can you send your `NewCongressViewModel` when you redirect to `New` view?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TempData` to pass model data to a redirect request. You can pass simple types like string, int, Guid etc. If you want to pass a complex type object via TempData, you have can serialize your object to a string and pass that. Specific to your case, you can use:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult New(NewCongressViewModel viewModel)
 {
   var complexObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModel);
   TempData["mymodel"] = complexObj;
   return RedirectToAction("New");
 }

public ActionResult New()
{
    if (TempData["mymodel"] is string complexObj )
    {
        var getModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewCongressViewModel>(complexObj); //Your model values can now be accessed
    }
    return View();
}
```

Note: The value of `TempData` persists only from one request to the next.

Comment: The method New returns me yet a html code and i dont wanna it, i just want go to another page (View New) with the model

Comment: @Julio In this line: `public ActionResult New(NewCongressViewModel viewModel)`, are you getting values in the `viewModel` variable? If that is the case, then my solution would work. In your `New` view, you can do a `return View(getModel);`. This will show your `New` view with the model that was passed to it.

Comment: I think the problem is in the AJAX request, he must get a request from the Controller

Comment: @Julio Have you tried debugging your AJAX script to see what you get on your console? Or have you tried debugging in your Controller to see if you get your values for `NewCongressViewModel` ?

Comment: The NewCongressViewModel get the values from the AJAX scrpit but the Controller New just send to the AJAX the View HTML code and does nothing more

Comment: Ohh, you have to redirect from your AJAX then. In your `success` method, this line will redirect you to the `New` view: `window.location.href="@Url.Action("New", "Home")";` .Also what do you see in this: `console.log("sucess= "+response);`

Comment: You rigth it was the problem thank you @RahulSharma